# why is cythonization not working for me when I have a simple file that takes in arguments?

Tags: python-3.x, cython, cythonize

I followed this procedure, which I integrated from several webpages:

```
import distutils.core
import Cython.Build
distutils.core.setup( ext_modules = Cython.Build.cythonize("main_file_that_accepts_sysv_args.py"))
distutils.core.setup( ext_modules = Cython.Build.cythonize("helper_file.py"))
```

I ran this code, and it went without errors, creating c files with extensions .c.

I then ran

gcc -shared -pthread -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing       -Ipython/anaconda3/include/python3.9 -o main main_file_that_accepts_sysv_args.c

however, when trying to run main, I get segfault, even when giving the proper arguments.

There are several things to note: the real file to optimize is actually helper_file.py (which I do have .c file for), but I am not sure if I should just add it to the list of files in the above gcc command.

I am also not sure why I am getting segfault to begin with, and if I should further modify the C code in any way.

I am using python 3.9.

What steps am I missing?

EDIT

Following the comments below I tried instead:

gcc -shared -pthread -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing       -Ipython/anaconda3/include/python3.9 -o main.so main_file_that_accepts_sysv_args.c

gcc -shared -pthread -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing       -Ipython/anaconda3/include/python3.9 -o helper.so helper_file.c

gcc -o main main.so helper.so

but I get a lot of undefined reference errors by the linker.

So I suppose I need to link the cythonize main library (??) but I am not sure where it is.

I am a bit fuzzy here on the details...

Comment: I would assume, that even if the artifact doesn't end with .so it is still a shared object (`--shared` option).

Comment: I'd suggest not compiling your main file and just running it as a Python script that imports `helper_file`. Making executables from Cython rarely does what people want (because it's very very difficult to bundle multiple modules together so the executable isn't standalone and so the whole thing is a bit pointless)